# Can you have multiple instances of Plupload on the same HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, plupload

Is it possible to embed several instances of Plupload on the same form?

If so, is it also possible to safely remove the manual 'upload' button so that I can programmatically trigger the uploading of all files when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, as long as each Plupload instance has a unique ID. Had a response from Plupload's creator [on his forum](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=3759).

Comment: but how to set instance ID? Nothing about instance ID is mentioned in the documentation. The link `on his forum` is also dead. Edit: found possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138386/how-to-make-a-loop-for-multiple-plupload/17189838#17189838