# Plupload Jquery: Multiple Upload Instances On The Same Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, plupload

I have using the Plupload plugin in my application. But I couldn't apply multiple instances on the same page. Here is my code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <title>Plupload - Custom example</title>

        <!-- production -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>


        <!-- debug 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/moxie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.dev.js"></script>
        -->

    </head>
    <body style="font: 13px Verdana; background: #eee; color: #333">

        <h1>Custom example</h1>

        <p>Shows you how to use the core plupload API.</p>

        <div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
        <br />

        <div id="container">
            <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> 
            <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
        </div>

    <div id="container">
            <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> 
            <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
        </div>

        <br />
        <pre id="console"></pre>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Custom example logic

            var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
                browse_button: 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
                container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
                url: 'upload.php',
                flash_swf_url: '../js/Moxie.swf',
                silverlight_xap_url: '../js/Moxie.xap',
                filters: {
                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                    mime_types: [
                        {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png"},
                        {title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip"}
                    ]
                },
                init: {
                    PostInit: function() {
                        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

                        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                            uploader.start();
                            return false;
                        };
                    },
                    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
                            $('#filelist').append(
                                    '<div id="' + file.id + '">' +
                                    file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
                                    '<a href="" class="remove btn error">X</a></div>'
                                    );
                            $('#uploadfiles').css('display', 'initial');
                            $('#filelist').append('<br/>');

                            $('#' + file.id + ' a.remove').first().click(function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                up.removeFile(file);
                                $('#' + file.id).next("br").remove();
                                $('#' + file.id).remove();
                                if (up.files.length == 0) {
                                    $('#uploadfiles').css('display', 'none');
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    },
                    FilesRemoved: function(up, files) {
                        // Called when files where removed from queue
                        console.log('[FilesRemoved]');

                        plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                            console.log('  File:', file);
                        });
                    },
                    removeFile: function(file) {
                        var i;

                        for (i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (files[i].id === file.id) {
                                return this.splice(i, 1)[0];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    splice: function(start, length) {
                        var removed;

                        // Splice and trigger events
                        removed = files.splice(start === undef ? 0 : start, length === undef ? files.length : length);

                        this.trigger("FilesRemoved", removed);
                        this.trigger("QueueChanged");

                        return removed;
                    },
                    UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
                    },
                    FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
                        // Called when a file has finished uploading
                        console.log('[FileUploaded] File:', file, "Info:", info);
                    },
                    ChunkUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
                        // Called when a file chunk has finished uploading
                        console.log('[ChunkUploaded] File:', file, "Info:", info);
                    },
                    Error: function(up, args) {
                        // Called when a error has occured
                        console.log('[error] ', args);
                    }

                }
            });
            uploader.init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know the problem is because of unique ID. Is there any way to implement multiple upload instance with this. Here the first upload working correctly.

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: this might be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17189838/1236044