# How do I create two pluploader objects on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I'm struggling to create two "pluploader" objects on the same web page (however, I suspect whatever the solution to my problem is, it will apply to any object).

I have the pluploader javascript in a method of a class that I call twice but pass in different variables. I will post a representative example of the code in order to try and keep clarity.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var JTpluploader = "<?php echo $this->browseButtonID; ?>";
var browseButtonDivID = "<?php echo $this->browseButtonDivID; ?>";
var dragDropAreaID = "<?php echo $this->dragDropAreaID; ?>";
var pluploadUploadContainerID = "<?php echo $this->pluploadUploadContainerID; ?>";

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/* **************************** */
// SET UP NECESSARY VARIABLES
/* **************************** */

JTpluploader = "<?php echo $this->browseButtonID; ?>";
browseButtonDivID = "<?php echo $this->browseButtonDivID; ?>";
dragDropAreaID = "<?php echo $this->dragDropAreaID; ?>";
pluploadUploadContainerID = "<?php echo $this->pluploadUploadContainerID; ?>";

// create the uploader and pass in variables that I set up earlier in $plupload_init
window[JTpluploader] = new plupload.Uploader(<?php echo json_encode($plupload_init); ?>);
```

I then access the pluploader like this...

```
window[JTpluploader].bind('Init', function(up){
var uploaddiv = $('#'+pluploadUploadContainerID);
// rest of code in here...
}
```

It all appeared to be working but I noticed an issue when I tried to 'hide' and 'show' divs from button clicks etc.

This code doesn't work...

```
showHideAfterUploadClicked();

function showHideAfterUploadClicked() {
jQuery('#'+browseButtonDivID).hide();
}
```

This code is called twice at runtime with different variables being passed in but (after peppering my code with 'alerts' and 'console logs' it seems that the second time the code is called I am overwriting the variables. This is also backed up by the fact that the second uploader works.

I'm sure I should be implementing this differently but (as I'm sure you can tell) I'm very new to javascript/jquery and so I'm unaware of the best way to do this. I've been googling the .bind function to see if there was a way to somehow set up an object or class or something along those lines to handle all this but I'm getting myself lost?

Help. :-)

Comment: maybe this can be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17189838/1236044